# Check a string for non-numeric characters in VBScript

Tags: string, search, vbscript

I'm working on a Windows application that's written in VBScript and I need to check a string for any non-numeric characters, specifically anything a-z. I realize I could probably do this using the InStr() function in conjunction with a loop that checks for a-z but that just seems ridiculous. I have very little experience in VBScript so I really don't know where to go on this.

What's a good method for handling this kind of situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[a-z]"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True
hasMatches = re.Test("12345abc")

If hasMatches = True Then
    ' it has letters
End If
```

Comment: Worked great, btw. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehs9h2x9%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function?

```
If IsNumeric(x) Then y = CDbl(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

a little late but an answer.

if you work with isnumeric and you set a Not in front to check if there is NO NUMBER. But every sign like !"§$%& and so on will be ignored and will be put into the check